# Cannot Edit ~/.vimrc file without both E297 error and E667 From Appearing

Tags: vimrc, bash

I am SSHing into an Ubuntu machine where I use Bash as the shell. I used to be able to edit my `~/.vimrc` file very easily. Now, whenever I try to write to it, I get a warning

> ```
> E297 write error in swap file
> ```

and also after typing in text, I cannot save the changes. Vim tells me that

> ```
> E667: Fsync failed.
> ```

In order to exit the file, I simply have to type the `:q!` (force quit command).

This also happens to my `~/.bashrc` file, and any other `~/.file` that I access. However, I can successfully edit files in any directory outside of `/usr2/`.

This is an NFS file system and `ls -ld ~` outputs that I have `rwx` permissions on that directory, and that I am the owner of it:

`drwxrwxrwx 9 my_name users ... /usr2/my_name`

It is odd because I am the owner of the file and have reading and writing permissions:

```
ls -l ~/.vimrc
-rwxr----- 1 my_name users 172 Aug 18 14:18 /usr2/my_name/.vimrc
```

I also have only used 54% of my allotted disk space by my system admin, so it cannot be a disk space issue. I also cannot find any `.vimrc.swp` files.

Comment: Are there perhaps permission problems with other directories? For instance, does `ls -ld ~` show you correct permissions to your home directory itself?

Comment: (Not the source of your problem, but note that I'd expect your `.vimrc` file shouldn't have the "execute" bit set... But that's just a minor hygiene issue, probably not really the source of the issue you're having.)

Comment: See also `:swapname` which will tell you the name (and location) of the swap file for the file you're editing. What does `:set directory?` tell you? (That configures where swap files are supposed to be stored...)

Comment: Hello @filbranden, I have rwx permissions on /usr2/my_name directory, as shown by the `ls -ld ~` command. Running `:swapname` shows me that there actually is indeed a swap file in _/usr2/my_name/.vimrc.swp_. Runnnig `:set directory?` shows `directory=.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`. Should I delete the swap file?

Comment: I'm wondering if this `/usr2` directory is a weird filesystem... You can see that with `df -Th ~` which will tell you the filesystem type. Please [edit] the question to add more information, it's hard to follow information from comments... (Also include the aforementioned `ls -ld ~` output shen you edit the question...)

Comment: *"I can normally edit files in a relative path"* That's odd... So `vim .vimrc` works, but `vim ~/.vimrc` doesn't? When you're in your home, `pwd` (in the shell) tells you you're in `/usr2` or somewhere else? Is the `$HOME` variable set correctly? Are there symlinks involved somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, `vim .vimrc` runs into the same problem. My home directory is (`echo $HOME`) is /usr2/my_name. If I am in any directory outside /usr2/, then I can edit files with no problem.

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx` 

Comment: You can disable swapfiles by adding `set directory=` (with an empty value) to your vimrc... Maybe this will make your problems go away? I wouldn't call that a solution (it's just hiding/masking the problem) but maybe that's good enough for you?

Comment: Since this is a company-issued machine and other users can log into it and make directories in /usr2/, it is probably something with that. Is it possible to make a new .vim file in /local/mnt/random_dir_name instead? And use that for vim? My last ditch effort is to copy the ~/.vimrc file into another backup file, delete ~/.vimrc, and make it again

Comment: You can probably work around this... But it seems that this `/usr2` filesystem is backed by some storage which lacks proper POSIX semantics and is breaking Vim... (I would be surprised if that doesn't break many other applications in Ubuntu as well.) I would recommend raising an issue with the administrators of those machines and storage so they can take a closer look at it.

Comment: If you want to work around it, there's the `MYVIMRC` environment variable that you can set, or also `VIMINIT` which stores an Ex command to execute and you can use `:source` there... See Vim's `:help VIMINIT` for more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had installed a version control tool called "repo" on the home directory of the company computer (/usr2/user_name) that had a very small disk partition allocated to it by the system admin. It took up 5GB of space. I removed it and already had it installed in a different directory.

After the removal and freeing up of disk space, I was able to edit my ~/.vimrc and ~/.bashrc files that are in the home directory.

It also turns out that my company has a special tool for checking users disk quota, and running `df` command was not accurate enough (I had not used 54% of quota, I had used 100%). Pretty much, just make sure to have enough disk space available.